# How to create a new csv from a csv that separated cell

Tags: python, django

I created a function for convert the csv.
The main topic is: get a csv file like:

```
,features,corr_dropped,var_dropped,uv_dropped
0,AghEnt,False,False,False
```

and I want to conver it to an another csv file:

|  | features | corr_dropped | var_dropped | uv_dropped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AghEnt | False | False | False |

I created a function for that but it is not working. The output is same as the input file.

**function**

```
def convert_file():
    input_file = "../input.csv"
    output_file = os.path.splitext(input_file)[0] + "_converted.csv"
    df = pd.read_table(input_file, sep=',')
    df.to_csv(output_file, index=False, header=True, sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
```

this works with your data. There is not much difference though. The only thing that changes is that the empty space before the first delimiter now has `Unnamed: 0` in there.

Is that what you wanted? (Still not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, as you are importing a csv and exporting the same data as a csv without really doing anything with it. the output example you showed is just a formated version of your initial data. but formating is not something csv can do.)